# clickcounter not repeating with setinterval(javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make it so that an image can be clicked 3 times before it disappears, and I would like that function to repeat itself. At this point it only works the first time the image pops up, after that it disappears after 1 click. Sorry for the confusing code.(It works now)

```
     let clickMonster3=0;
    const monsterCounter3=()=>clickMonster3++;
    
     function monster003(){
       
        
            if(clickMonster3==3){
            this.style.display='none'
        }else{
            monsterCounter3()
        }
         wolfmonster3.onclick=monster003;
        
         setInterval(monster003,6000);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "_and I would like that function to repeat itself_"? Currently your `setInterval` repeats the same action as your click event does. So it increments the `clickMonster3` every 6 seconds. And what do you mean by "_the first time the image pops up_"? Nothing in your code handles subsequent images showing up.

Comment: "wolfmonster3" is an image.

Comment: and the first time this image shows up on the screen, I can click it 3 times before it disappears, but the next time it shows up (after 6 seconds) it will disappear after 1 click.

Comment: I'm not sure how it shows up again after 6 seconds, since you only ever set the display to `none` and never remove it. But it makes sense for the next invocation to remove it immediately. You never reset `clickMonster3` back to `0`, so it remains on the `3` it was the time before that.

Comment: I think I just confused everyone, but I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

keep on each image an attribute that denotes it's click count. increase it on every click and if it's 3 then set the image to be display:none;

you should setInterval(monster003,6000) only once

```js
function newMonster() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "https://picsum.photos/100";
  img.setAttribute("data-click-count", 0);
  img.onclick = function() {
    var current = +this.getAttribute("data-click-count") + 1
    this.setAttribute("data-click-count", current);
    if (current == 3) {
      this.style.display = 'none'
    }
  }
  document.body.append(img)
}


setInterval(newMonster, 3000);
newMonster();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
setInterval(monster003,6000);
```

into

```
setInterval(() => {
   clickMonster3 = 0;
   monster003();
}, 6000);
```

You need to reset your counter variable - in this case as I see it is called `clickMonster3` - back to 0 so it can be counted 3 times.

Word of advice: call your variables and methods with some sense, and write your code more tidy, with insets, no extra spaces or rows etc.

Comment: thank you, it is written better, just had to change it before I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Save click count in a [`data-attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on the image. Use `setTimeout` within the handler instead of `setInterval`. The snippet uses [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to handle the initial click.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.dataset.clickcount) {
    console.clear();
    evt.target.dataset.clickcount = +evt.target.dataset.clickcount + 1;
    if (+evt.target.dataset.clickcount < 3) {
      console.log(`${evt.target.dataset.img} clicked ${
        +evt.target.dataset.clickcount} time(s), hiding 2 seconds`);
      evt.target.classList.add(`hide`);
      return setTimeout(_ => evt.target.classList.remove(`hide`), 2000);
    }
    console.log(`${evt.target.dataset.img} clicked ${
      +evt.target.dataset.clickcount} times, hiding permanently`);
    return evt.target.style.display = `none`;
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s 0s;
}

img.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="//cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/05/02/17/24/ground-45742_960_720.png" 
  data-clickcount="0" data-img="img1">
  
<img src="//cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/01/mountains-736886_960_720.jpg" 
  data-clickcount="0" data-img="img2">
```